# MAPI_E_FAILONEPROVIDER error is thrown when the user is logged off and Outlook 2016/2019 is accessed in a windows application using MAPI

Tags: outlook, mfc, mapi

In a Windows application, calling OpenMsgStore function is throwing error when I am trying to open the default primary store for 'Outlook' 2016 Outlook profile only when the user is logged off. When the user is logged in, all the MAPI functions work successfully.

```cpp
HRESULT hr = MAPILogonEx(0,
                         const_cast<LPTSTR>((LPCTSTR)m_strProfileTemplate), NULL,
                         MAPI_EXTENDED | MAPI_NEW_SESSION | MAPI_NO_MAIL | MAPI_UNICODE,
                         &m_pSession);

SRestriction sres;
SPropValue spv;
LPSRowSet pStores = NULL;
hr = m_pSession->GetMsgStoresTable(0, &pStoresTable);

sres.rt = RES_PROPERTY;                          
sres.res.resProperty.relop = RELOP_EQ;
sres.res.resProperty.ulPropTag = PR_DEFAULT_STORE;
sres.res.resProperty.lpProp = &spv;
spv.ulPropTag = PR_DEFAULT_STORE;
spv.Value.b   = TRUE;

hr = HrQueryAllRows(pStoresTable,(LPSPropTagArray) &sptCols,&sres,NULL,0,&pStores);
    
ULONG flags = MDB_WRITE| MDB_NO_MAIL;
hr = m_pSession->OpenMsgStore(NULL,pStores->aRow[0].lpProps[0].Value.bin.cb,
                              (LPENTRYID)pStores->aRow[0].lpProps[0].Value.bin.lpb,
                              NULL,
                              flags | MDB_ONLINE,
                              &pPrimaryMessageStore);
```

The call for `OpenMsgStore` fails with the `MAPI_E_FAILONEPROVIDER` error when the user is logged off from the system and the service executes the above code.
However this function is successful when user is logged in to system.

How does the MAPI work if the user, trying to access outlook as a scheduled service is logged off from the system?

Comment: [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2).

Comment: @IInspectable that is Extended MAPI, not Outlook automation.

Answer (score 0):

Try including the `MAPI_NT_SERVICE` flag to the `MAPILogonEx` call.

That means the caller is running as a Windows service. Callers that are not running as a Windows service should not set this flag; callers that are running as a service must set this flag.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK if OAuth is used, MAPI system cannot find the cached credentials and opening the message store fails.

Comment: In a microsoft link it is given : if your application requires mailbox access by using Extended MAPI, and if Modern Authentication is required, you can establish an initial connection by using Outlook, and then use the same Outlook profile to connect to the mailbox by using your custom application. This lets Outlook acquire OAuth tokens that Extended MAPI can then reuse. how can I setup an initial connection with Outlook? Can I use MAPI interfaces to CreateProfile, CreateMsgService and ConfigureMsgService to create profile?

Comment: Yes, you can use Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi or only) or Redemption/Profman (I am their author - any language), but the user would still need to go through the OAuth prompts before Outlook woudl be able to do anything. And that would not do anything to help you with your original problem.

Comment: What do you suggest in order to fix the issue of OAuth authentication failing for MAPI? Authentication passes when the user is logged on to the machine. when user is logged off and the process request for opening the Default message store, it fails. How does MAPI work in these 2 scenarios?

Comment: Well, MAPI does not work in that scenario :-)